# How do I validate a input (type file) and use it with action from react router 6.4+?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I would like to upload multiple files to a backend and am using react router's  form element for that, and "action" to submit the files. I intend to show a preview for every file uploaded and have a cap of 2 files as well.

This is how my code looks like currently.

```
const MAX_COUNT = 2;

export async function action({ request }: { request: Request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  console.log("FORM DATA", formData);
  if (Array.from(formData.keys()).length > MAX_COUNT) {
    return { error: `You can only upload a maximum of ${MAX_COUNT} files` };
  }
  const results = await uploadCheatsheet(formData);

  console.log(results);

  return null;
}

interface UploadActionData {
  error: string;
}

function Upload() {
  const uploadActionData = useActionData() as UploadActionData;
  
  return (
    <>

      <Form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
         <other code...>
              <input
                multiple
                name="files"
                id="file-upload"
                // className="hidden"
                accept=".xlsx"
                type="file"
              />
              <label htmlFor="file-upload">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() =>
                    document?.getElementById("file-upload")?.click()
                  }
                  className="border-solid border-1 border-blue-600 text-blue-600"
                >
                  Browse Files
                </button>
              </label>
  
              <div id="preview-files" className="self-end mr-4">
         
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {uploadActionData && uploadActionData?.error && (
            <p>{uploadActionData?.error}</p>
          )}

          <button
            type="submit"
            className="mt-12 border-solid border-1 border-blue-600 text-blue-600 disabled:bg-slate-300 disabled:text-slate-600 disabled:border-slate-600"
            // disabled={fileLimit || uploadedFiles.length === 0}
          >
            Update
          </button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}

export default Upload;
```

It seems to me like I need the files to be in a state to allow the user to add and remove files to be submitted for uploading, and also to display the preview. However "action" cannot access any states I create inside Upload component. Can anyone share how I should approach this please?